# Override Woocommerce function

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to fully change logic of function `get_discounted_price` in `WC_Cart class`.

In child `functions.php` i have wrote:

```
function get_discounted_price_new( $values, $price, $add_totals = false )
{
 //My code that extends standart function
}
add_action('get_discounted_price', 'get_discounted_price_new');
```

But i do not see any changes. Where is mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I think do_action is not required.

You need the filter `woocommerce_get_discounted_price`.

Check the following code -

```
// define the woocommerce_get_discounted_price callback 
function filter_woocommerce_get_discounted_price( $price, $values, $instance ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    return $price; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_discounted_price', 'filter_woocommerce_get_discounted_price', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I have found this, but such changes, that i need to do, i can't make with filter. I need fully rewrite this function

Comment: can you specify what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I need to remove coupon sale to every odd product in cart when coupon is applied. 
I check coupon name, and counter of product, that i ++ after each iteration.

So in your answer $price - it is result price after coupon is applied.